# Filtering Data from sql server

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, filtering

I have a web page that returns over 36000 items from sql server and I need ideas to filter the data. So far my ideas are paging through letters and a text search box which uses the following sql -

```
    select          O_ObjectID, 
                rtrim(O_Name) as O_Name
    from            A_Object
    where           O_Name like @NamePrefix + '%' OR O_Name like '% ' + @NamePrefix + '%'
    order by        O_Name
```

So any thoughts in which I can filter data?

Comment: Do you want to actually limit what is returned or do you want to page and return everything but only a bit at a time? We need a bit more info here.

Comment: @telarian I want to limit what is returned

Comment: It's really difficult to tell you how to filter your data without a heck of a lot more information. It all depends. What information do you need? If you have a table full of data, how can I tell you what part of it you need to see? Are you trying to only display the records where O_Name contains whatever you have in @NamePrefix? If so then it seems like you have a good start. It's hard to tell you what else you can filter out when we have no idea what you're looking for or even what your other fields are though.

Comment: Oh yes and %xxxxx% will include in it's results anything that xxxxx% would, so there really isn't any point in doing them both.

Comment: @telarian yea i'm trying to display the records which O_Name contains @NamePrefix. So O_Name is contents that are selected to be attached to permissions. I also filter by permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a possible resultset of up to 36000 rows, paging won't help you much because no user is willing to browse more than 3 pages of search results - Honestly: Did you ever bother to click through more that 5 pages of Google search results before refining your search term?

Try to identify columns that would make up good filter criteria (besides O_Name), create a search form and limit the result to `TOP 300`.

Of course if your table actually only consists of `O_ObjectID` and `O_Name` you pretty much stuck with "Starts with" and "Contains" from your sample query ... you could add "Ends with" just to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

Paging in classic asp -- it's been a while.  It helps if you've got some read-only table to work from -- gets a little tricky if people can delete records from your table.

Anyway, here is a decent attempt:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210506081930/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041206-1.shtml

I'd suggest moving to .net when you can, as it has controls with built-in paging that works much better.

Comment: I'd really recommend this article for an indepth review of various ways of paging through a recordset using classic asp and sql server - http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-page-through-a-recordset.html